# Why does the C++ compiler fail to optimize "if(test) --foo" to "foo -= test"?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

I have a function which finds the next power of two for a given integer. If the integer is a power of two it returns the power.

Pretty straight forward:

```
char nextpow2if(int a)
{
    char foo = char(32 - __builtin_clz(a));
    bool ispow2 = !(a & a-1);
    if (ispow2) --foo;
    return foo;
}
```

However after compiling with gcc 6 with -O2, after inspecting the generated assembly, I see that this is compiled with seemingly useless instruction `cmovne` after calculating foo-1. Even worse with gcc5 and older I get an actual `jne` branch in the code.

The faster way to compile this would be as if I had written the following function:

```
char nextpow2sub(int a)
{
    char foo = char(32 - __builtin_clz(a));
    bool ispow2 = !(a & a-1);
    return foo - ispow2;
}
```

This code is correctly compiled by all compilers to the shortest (and fastest) possible assembly with a `sete` and subtraction for the bool.

Why does the compiler fail to optimize the first one? This seems like a really easy to identity case. Why does gcc 5 and older compile this to an actual `jne` branch? Is there an edge case between the two versions, that I can't see, that might cause them to behave differently?

PS: Live demo [here](https://godbolt.org/g/mTZ4xx)

Edit: I haven't tested the performance with gcc 6 but with gcc 5 the latter is about two times faster (well on a synthetic performanse test, at least). This is what actually led me to ask this question.

Comment: Don't spam tags for unrelated languages!

Comment: *"The faster way to compile this would be as if I had written the following function:"* Did you measure that? How much faster is it?

Comment: Are you comparing the performance by number of assembly code generated ? That is not a good way to do it (though it may be true in some cases).

Comment: On GCC 5 the latter is about two times faster.

Comment: Alright, if that measurement was done correctly, that is certainly significant. Not much we SO guys can do about that though, better complain to the compiler devs.

Comment: It's not a complaint, but a question (which might turn to a complaint to the appropriate people :) ) Perhaps there is something in the code that makes it impossible to optimize. I can't see it, but maybe someone can. Or someone with the approrpiate knowledge could say that it is an actual known compiler issue

Comment: At least I can't see why this should not be optimized either. (Not my dv btw in case you wondered.)

Comment: There is no inherent reason why this couldn't be compiled as if you wrote the second version. Clang does it. Just a missed optimization.

Comment: Playing with your live demo (which was really helpful) some of the compilers do make this optimization. armv8-a clang trunk produces fairly elegant code, 7 instructions.  ellcc, 8 instructions. RISCV not so much. 70 instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler could indeed perform this optimization in this specific case without violating the standard. But consider the following slightly different case:

```
char nextpow2sub(int a)
{
    char foo = char(32 - __builtin_clz(a));
    bool ispow2 = !(a & a-1);
    return foo - (5 * ispow2);
}

char nextpow2if(int a)
{
    char foo = char(32 - __builtin_clz(a));
    bool ispow2 = !(a & a-1);
    if (ispow2) foo = foo - 5;
    return foo;
}
```

The only change I made here is that I'm subtracting by 5 rather than 1. If you compile using gcc 6.x and compare, you'll see that the generated binary code is of the same size for both functions. I expect also both them to have more or less the same performance.

This shows that the optimization algorithm that the compiler has used has been designed to handle the general case. That said, even for the case of subtracting by 1, I expect (using gcc 6.x) that there will be a tiny difference in performance on any modern processor that supports instruction-level parallelism and register renaming.

> This code is correctly compiled by all compilers to the shortest (and
>   fastest) possible assembly with a `sete` and subtraction for the `bool`.

How did you know that this is the shortest and fastest  possible code? Yes, it is shorter and faster but do you have a proof that this is the shortest and fastest? Also you cannot give such a statement without specifying a particular architecture and microarchitecture.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the reason for this could be that `bool` is typically stored within a byte. Therefore, the compiler may not be able to safely assume the actual memory is *exactly* equal to 1. The `true`/`false` check probably just compares against zero. Subtraction, however, could be a different story with side effects.

See [example code on Ideone](http://ideone.com/pDus2G):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union charBool
{
    unsigned char aChar;
    bool aBool;
};

int main() 
{
    charBool var;
    charBool* varMemory = &var;

    var.aBool = 65;
    std::cout << "a boolean = " << var.aBool << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a char = " << var.aChar << std::endl;
    std::cout << "varMemory = " << (*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(varMemory))) << std::endl;

    var.aChar = 98;   // note: Ideone C++ compiler resolves this to zero, hence bit0 seems to be the only checked
    std::cout << "a boolean = " << var.aBool << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a char = " << var.aChar << std::endl;
    std::cout << "varMemory = " << (*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(varMemory))) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That results in:

```
a boolean = 1
a char = 
varMemory = 
a boolean = 0
a char = b
varMemory = b
```

(note: first two chars are unprintable)

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers anything. The only actual reason to not optimize this to the faster code would be finding some difference between both variants under the as-if rule.

Comment: @BaummitAugen briefly: seems cheap to assume anything other than zero in a boolean is `true`. If you wanted to enable this "exactly 1 for decrementation" optimization, to perform the first - you'd have to always check for side effects (i.e. if someone bases on =1). Code above is a play to modify a boolean internal memory (as assignment might set it to 0/1).

Comment: Such might (and should) be the case with a `volatile bool`. But in my example, the compiler has every opportunity to see that the boolean is either 0 or 1

Comment: @hauron *"you'd have to always check for side effects"* But the `bool` in question is not some arbitrary byte from god knows where, the compiler can see its initialization and its entire lifetime by just inspecting 4 loc. That's not unreasonable.

Comment: The problem here was that GCC was *not* storing that bool in a byte. Clang does, and then it can just subtract.

Comment: @harold: That seems to clear things. So the culprit seems to be order of optimization. Sounds reasonable.  So it probably is a bug, but not a major one.  It would be nice to see this as an answer and not as an obscure comment.  Especially if you have links to back up the claim.

Comment: @stefaanv the godbolt link in the question shows it, anyway I suspect it decided too early to merge the decrement with the subtract from 32, causing "branch conversion" to fail. But I don't know for sure